# mysql unique constraint fails with null values?

Tags: mysql

We have a two column unique constraint for web scraping.  url + javascriptPath.  url cannot be null and javascriptPath is null a ton.

BUT when we insert these two values, it succeeds instead of properly failing

- (1, "http://myurl", null)
- (2, "http://myurl", null)

and we end up with two rows so when we search on http://myurl and javascriptPath=null, it fails on us as we expected one result.

How to do this uniqueness constraint?

thanks,
Dean

Comment: `javascriptPath = null` should be `javascriptPath IS null`. Voting to close this as a typo.

Comment: Unfortunately (or not, depending on your perspective), MySQL allows you to insert `NULL` into a unique key more than once.